# multi language flash chart recommendation?

Tags: flash, charts, right-to-left, multilingual

I need a good multi language flash chart for my company's portal, can you recommend one?

Already have tried fusion-charts, amCharts, and also OpenChart -
But they are not supporting right-to-left, and the API is not simple (they require a complex XML).

Requirements:

- good looking
- easy to implement (simple api)
- customizable
- well documented
- not expensive

Comment: Flex has charting components, why not make your own charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "[MultiChart](http://chart.sqlcode.org)" - for displaying arabic data, was very easy to use and it has brilliant animation.